# Delete all files of a folder from a subfolder

Tags: php

Suppose I have all my pages in my public_html folder. There is another folder named 'temp' and it is not inside my public_html folder . I want to make a cron job which will delete all my files and folders which are in 'temp' folder. But my cron job is in 'public_html' folder. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

You can access the temp folder with this path: `../temp`.

Use that script to remove its containing files:

```
<?php
$dir = '../temp';
if (!$dh = @opendir($dir))
    die('Could not read directory ' . $path);
$i = 0;
while (false !== ($obj = readdir($dh))) {
    if (is_file($dir . '/' . $obj))
        continue;
    if (!@unlink($dir . '/' . $obj))
        echo 'Could not delete file ' . $obj . '<br/>';
    else
        $i++;
}
echo $i . ' files deleted';
```